# How to merge 2 lists in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to merge 2 lists so the output is the following:

```
List<String> array1 = ["John", "Bob", "Fred", "June", "Tom"];
List<String> array2 = ["House", "Flat", "Bungalow"];

List<String> output = //["John", "House", "Bob", "Flat", "Fred", "Bungalow", "June", "Tom"]
```

How can I achieve this? I've had a look at the [zip](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/quiver.iterables/zip.html) function in the quiver library but it only returns a list as long as the shortest list that's passed into it.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I essentially want to do the same as the zip function but if one array is longer than the other, I just want to append the left over items on to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything ready-to-use, but this should do what you want:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  List<String> array1 = ["John", "Bob", "Fred", "June", "Tom"];
  List<String> array2 = ["House", "Flat", "Bungalow"];

  List<String> output = List<String>(array1.length + array2.length);
  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < math.min(array1.length, array2.length); i++) {
    output[i * 2] = array1[i];
    output[i * 2 + 1] = array2[i];
  }
  print(output);
  if (array1.length != array2.length) {
    if (array1.length > array2.length) {
      output.setRange(i * 2, output.length, array1.sublist(i));
    } else {
      output.setRange(i * 2, output.length, array2.sublist(i));
    }
  }
  print(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but won't this just append one array onto the other? I've updated the question to hopefully add more detail.

Comment: So the order is relevant? I thought you just don't want duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

i think this should work too

```
void main() {
  var list1 = ["John", "Bob", "Fred", "June", "Tom"];
  var list2 = ["House", "Flat", "Bungalow"];
  var list3 = [...list1, ...list2];

  print(list1);
  print(list2);
  print(list3);
}
```

the outputs should be like this (tested in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/))

```
[John, Bob, Fred, June, Tom]
[House, Flat, Bungalow]
[John, Bob, Fred, June, Tom, House, Flat, Bungalow]
```

Comment: This simply appends one list onto the other, that's not what the questioner is asking. They want to merge the two.

Comment: sorry? i create a new list and merge the other 2 using spread operator, why is that weren't counted as merging? also. i'd better use `list.addAll(anotherList)` to append a list.

Comment: ah, my bad. my answer was, indeed didn't answer the question, sorry.

Comment: No problem it's great that you got involved and suggested an answer. I'd suggest you rewrite or delete your answer though to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is the following which is likely less efficient than Gunter's solution but is a bit more functional in nature and I like having multiple perspectives on how to solve a problem. If the arrays are as short as these, optimization on the join is likely not a concern anyways.

This solution creates an iterable on the indicies of the longest array and for each index i, creates potentially two entries from the input arrays if i is in both. Otherwise it includes only the element from the array which contains i.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

main() {
  List<String> array1 = ["John", "Bob", "Fred", "June", "Tom"];
  List<String> array2 = ["House", "Flat", "Bungalow"];

  //["John", "House", "Bob", "Flat", "Fred", "Bungalow", "June", "Tom"]
  List<String> output =
      Iterable.generate(math.max(array1.length, array2.length))
          .expand((i) sync* {
    if (i < array1.length) yield array1[i];
    if (i < array2.length) yield array2[i];
  }).toList();

  print(output);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is a core method that does exactly want you want. Take a look at my `merge` function:

```
import 'dart:math';

List<String> merge(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    List<String> output = [];

    var min_length = min(a.length, b.length);
    var max_length = max(a.length, b.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < min_length; i++) {
      output.add(a[i]);
      output.add(b[i]);
    }

    List<String> longer = a.length > b.length ? a : b;

    for(var i = min_length; i < max_length; i++) {
      output.add(longer[i]);
    }

    return output;
  }

void main() {
    merge(
      ["John", "Bob", "Fred", "June", "Tom"],
      ["House", "Flat", "Bungalow"]
    ).forEach((e) => print(e));

    print('------');

    merge(
      ["John", "Bob"],
      ["House", "Flat", "Bungalow"]
    ).forEach((e) => print(e));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `addAll()` method as in .

```
List<int> a =[1,2];  List<int> b =[1,2];
List<int> c =[];
c.addAll(a);
c.addAll(b);
```

Or `insertAll(index,Iterateable<>)`

```
List<int> a =[1,2];  
List<int> b =[1,2];
a.insertAll(a.length,b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a solution to this neither, and I didn't want to use List conversions or math functions if possible, so I wrote this:

```
extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<T> merge(Iterable<T> other) sync* {
    
    Iterator<T> iter1 = this.iterator;
    Iterator<T> iter2 = other.iterator;

    bool has1 = iter1.moveNext();
    bool has2 = iter2.moveNext();
    while(has1 && has2) {
      yield iter1.current;
      yield iter2.current;
      has1 = iter1.moveNext();
      has2 = iter2.moveNext();
    }
    while(has1) {
      yield iter1.current;
      has1 = iter1.moveNext();
    }
    while(has2) {
      yield iter2.current;
      has2 = iter2.moveNext();
    }
  }
}
```

It could probably be tidied up a bit but it works for now.

Examples [here](https://www.dartpad.dev/bc629bd90408a71596d48ff4198ef039).