# Dart combine two Lists in Alternate manner

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to populate a ListView in Flutter with different sources. So, I have two lists,

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']; #The list isn't of numeric type
list2 = ['2', '4'];
```

Now, I can combine them using the `spread` operator and get the following output

```
[a, b, c, 2, 4]
```

but I want the output to be like -

```
[a, 2, b, 4, c]
```

How can this be achieved? What's the most idiomatic approach?

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405066/how-to-merge-2-lists-in-dart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Builtin `Iterable` has no method `zip`, but you can write something like:

```dart
Iterable<T> zip<T>(Iterable<T> a, Iterable<T> b) sync* {
  final ita = a.iterator;
  final itb = b.iterator;
  bool hasa, hasb;
  while ((hasa = ita.moveNext()) | (hasb = itb.moveNext())) {
    if (hasa) yield ita.current;
    if (hasb) yield itb.current;
  }
}
```

then use `zip`

```dart
  final list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  final list2 = ['2', '4'];
  final res = zip(list1, list2);
  print(res); // (a, 2, b, 4, c)
```

Comment: Thanks, Spatz, I did not realize we can do this and this works well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this:

```
    List list1 = [1, 3, 5];
    List list2 = [2, 4];

    print([...list1, ...list2]..sort());
```

Comment: Well, you can sort anything you want... `..sort((a, b) => a.length.compareTo(b.length))`