# Merge Array List Flutter and saperate it

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, sorting, dart

my List

list1 = [1, 2, 3]

list2 = [A, B, C]

I wanted the combined output of:

[1, A | 2, B | 3, C]

help me to figure it out.

Comment: what does `[1, A | 2, B | 3, C]` even mean?

Comment: yes, I have to send the result array to my API.

Comment: `Iterable foo(Iterable i1, Iterable i2) sync* {
final iter1 = i1.iterator; iter1.moveNext();
final iter2 = i2.iterator; iter2.moveNext();

yield iter1.current;
while (iter1.moveNext()) {
yield '${iter2.current} | ${iter1.current}';
iter2.moveNext();
}
yield iter2.current;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
void main() {
 List list1 = [1, 2, 3];

 List list2 = ["A", "B", "C"];
 List list3 = [];
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i <= list1.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      list3.add(list1[i]);
    } else if (i == list1.length) {
      list3.add("${list2[i - 1 ]}");
    } else {
       list3.add("${list2[i - 1]} | ${list1[i]}");
    }
  }
  print(list3);  // [1, A | 2, B | 3, C]
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you want?

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var a = [1,2,3];
  var b = ["A","B","C"];
  List<String> c = [];
  for (final pairs in IterableZip([a, b])) {
    c.add(pairs[0].toString() + pairs[1].toString());
  }
  print(c); //prints [1A, 2B, 3C]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[I'm guessing this is what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043910/17211692)

So, just for some clarification about the answer, each list is being looped and added to another list one after another till there are no elements left.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [A,B,C]
```

loop each list

```
C = [1]
A[0]
C = [1,A]
B[0]
C = [1,A,2]
A[1]
C = [1,A,2,B]
B[1]
C = [1,A,2,B,3]
A[2]
C = [1,A,2,B,3,C]
B[2]
```

This will work even for uneven lists.
Hope it helps.